# Consulta com JOIN em 3 tabelas

Tags: mysql, query, select, join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
livroautor

        id  idautor  idlivro  
    ------  -------  ---------
         1        1     (NULL)
         2        2          2
         3        3          3
         4        4          4
         5        5          5
         6        6     (NULL)
         7        7          5
         8        8          2
         9        9          2
        10       10     (NULL)
```

livro

```
    id  titulo                      resumo  isbn    paginas  categoria                  
------  --------------------------  ------  ------  -------  ---------------------------
     1  Any Which Way You Can       (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)   Comedy                     
     2  Nitro Circus: The Movie     (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)   Action|Comedy|Documentary  
     3  Imaginary Heroes            (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)   Comedy|Drama               
     4  Nightmare in Las Cruces, A  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)   Documentary                
     5  Boys Next Door, The         (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)   Crime|Drama
```

autor

```
    id  nome     sobrenome    email                           
------  -------  -----------  --------------------------------
     1  Maddy    Garnsworthy  mgarnsworthy0@weather.com       
     2  Elsy     Kernoghan    ekernoghan1@miibeian.gov.cn     
     3  Eduard   Jehan        ejehan2@slideshare.net          
     4  Leone    Elizabeth    lelizabeth3@sciencedaily.com    
     5  Maurita  Ferraron     mferraron4@businessinsider.com  
     6  Sawyer   Szimoni      sszimoni5@tiny.cc               
     7  Emmy     Trudgeon     etrudgeon6@discuz.net           
     8  Wynnie   McKoy        wmckoy7@upenn.edu               
     9  Buiron   Vian         bvian8@wordpress.org            
    10  Bruis    Naisey       bnaisey9@nba.com
```

Preciso selecionar todos os livros que não possuem autores cadastrados, só que não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer. É suposto para eu usar `JOIN`, só que eu não tenho muito conhecimento desse comando.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: amigo, você não fez confusão quanto as colunas da tabela LivroAutor? a coluna livro tem campos nulos, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim:

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM livro l
INNER JOIN livroautor la on la.idlivro  = l.id
WHERE la.idautor not in(SELECT a.id FROM autor a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade você pode usar a expressão `NOT EXISTS` neste caso como a seguir:

```
SELECT l.*
  FROM livro l
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM livroautor la
                   WHERE la.idlivro = l.id)
```